# React Router: Route with nested params not hit

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my react app, I have set up routes like this

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <Route exact path="/" component={PostList} />
        <Route exact path="/:category" component={PostList} />
        <Route exact path="/:category/:postid" component={PostDetails} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`/` and `foo` are rendering the `PostList` component just fine. But when I try to reach the `PostDetails` component with for instance `/foo/bar`, it does not get hit.

I tried to play around with the order of the route definitions as well as with the `exact` prop, but no luck. Not getting any errors, the inspector in devtools just does not show any output where the component should be at.

What am I missing here? I am using **react-router-dom@4.2.2**.

Comment: What is your exact Route structure, any parent routes or children??

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri No, thats all. Updated the code to let you see the whole component.

Comment: When you hit `/foo/bar` you want `PostList` AND `PostDetails` to display or ONLY `PostDetails` ?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, but out of curiosity, what happens if you wrap the `<Route />` components with a `<Switch>` one? (import it from react-router-dom)

Comment: are you using BrowserRouter, also how are you visiting /foo/bar

Comment: I want to only show one component at a time. I added the `Switch` component but no difference. I visit this url `http://localhost:3000/foo/bar` in the browser. I am not using BrowserRouter (maybe I should?)

Comment: If you aren't using browserRouter, what you should visit is `http://localhost:3000/#/foo/bar`

Comment: Oh, I am in fact using Browser Router. Sorry for mixing it up and causing confusion.

Comment: Wrap your routes in `<Switch>` and the the route `/:foo/:bar` before `/:foo` in your render function. Here an example https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/admin/src/containers/App/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was simply a typo in the export of the component like this

```
export { defaut as PostDetails } from './post-details/PostDetails'
```

missing the `l` in default.

Strangely enough, I had no errors during transpiling. Sorry people and thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one of the routes to show, you should use a [`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch).

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={PostList} />
            <Route exact path="/:category" component={PostList} />
            <Route exact path="/:category/:postid" component={PostDetails} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the OP uses exact  and hence `Switch` wont make a difference here at all

Comment: I tried this and it did in fact not make a difference.